# how to convert nvarchar to time ,not datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
DECLARE @DateNow smalldatetime
SET @DateNow='12:30'
select @DateNow
-------------------------------------OR--------------------------------------
select CAST( '12:30' as datetime )
```

---

Result:  1900-01-01 12:30:00.000 (i don't want this)

But i need this result in time format not string not datetime?

Result:  12:30 (i  want this)

Comment: there is no datatype in SQL Server to only hold the time part of a date. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ykaratoprak - please look at my answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: how did you resolve this? seems like the question hasn't found the answer it wanted. Everyone is posting on getting the time part out of datetime. No one has addressed the "convert string to time or datetime" part :)

Answer (score 10):

Like José said, you can use CONVERT to display a datetime as date.  MSDN has a list of all [possible formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).  For example format 8 is hh:mi:ss:

```
 select convert(varchar(32),getdate(),8)
 12:51:21
```

Now, you can cut the seconds off by specifying less characters:

```
 select convert(varchar(5),getdate(),8)
 12:51
```

Another often used format is 121, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h):

```
 select convert(varchar(32),getdate(),121)
 2009-05-08 12:51:21.987
```

Where you can pick the time part like:

```
 select substring(convert(varchar(32),getdate(),121),12,5)
 12:51
```

Or to combine the string trickeries:

```
 select right(convert(varchar(16),getdate(),121),5)
 12:51
```

Right? Right!

Answer (score 9):

There's a [TIME](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-time-data-type-in-sql-server-2008) type in SQL Server 2008, but in previous versions, you can represent it as a varchar for display.

This is how you can retrieve the time portion of a DATETIME field in the format you want.

```
DECLARE @DateNow smalldatetime
SET @DateNow = GETDATE() -- 2009-05-08 12:58:02.680

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), @DateNow, 8) 
-- this returns the time portion as 12:58
```

Comment: +1 posted another answer to explain your char(5) trick in detail:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function.

By the way, there's no "TIME" datatype in SQL Server. So, the converted result will always be a STRING.

EDIT: There's no "TIME" datatype in SQL Server versions `<` SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you need to compare, add and/or subtract time (only) values, think about the possibility to use a INT to store the "TIME" value and then to CONVERT it to CHAR when displaying the result.